# Wait until another thread is working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here, I am waiting for html button element from the popup iframe window. When a popup is open then my block of code will fire the click event on time and it's working fine, but my query is wanting to wait until not get button.

I have used the nested function calling with timeout thread, so when I call then work, but don't wait and go to the next task.

```
setPrint();


function setPrint() {
 setTimeout(function () {
    var btnprint = null;
    var frame = $('#WindowFadeiFrame').get(0).contentDocument;
    var btn = $('#btn', frame);
    if (btn.length == 0) {
        btnprint == null
        console.log('not found');
    }
    else {
        btn.click();
        btnprint = btn;
        console.log('found now');
    }
    if (btnprint == null) {
        setPrint();
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Instead of timeout, use callback. This way you have more control.

Comment: can you explain me with example of callback please.

Comment: setPrint();
alert("hi");
 
Here, I don't want to call alert('hi) until not get button and click it.
setPrint() is nested function, so it call itself until not get button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function setPrint(callback) {

        var obj = setInterval(function () {

            var frame = $('#WindowFadeiFrame').get(0).contentDocument;
            var btn = $('#btn', frame);
            if (btn.length == 0) {
                console.log('not found');
            }
            else {
                btn.click();
                console.log('found now');
                clearInterval(obj);
                callback();
            }
        }, 100);

    }

    setPrint(callback)
    function callback() {
        // write all your code here which need to be executed after finding the control from iframe
        alert('');
    }
```